# Using is.na with Sapply function in R

Tags: r, lapply, na, sapply

Can anyone tell me what the line of code written below do?

`sapply(X, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) / nrow(airports) * 100`

What is understood is that it will drop `NA`s when it applies the sum function but keeps them in the matrix.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You are looping through the columns (with `sapply` - assuming `X` is a `data.frame`), get the number of NA elements (by doing the `sum` of logical vector (`is.na(x)`) and divide by the number of rows or airports.

Comment: I think it counts the percentage of NA's entries by row

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero not by row, by column. (And assuming that `X` is the same as `airports`, or is a subset of the `airports` columns, or has the same number of rows. That part isn't clear at all.)

Comment: @srkale it is not dropping anything. Dropping `NA`s in sum would like like `sum(..something.., na.rm = TRUE)`. In this case what is being summed is whether or not each value is `NA`, `sum(is.na(x))` essentially means "count the number of `NA`s in `x`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enough comments, time for an answer:

```
sapply(X,      # apply to each item of X (each column, if X is a data frame)
  function(x)  # this function:
    sum(is.na(x))  # count the NAs
) / nrow(airports) * 100  # then divide the result by the number of rows in the the airports object
  # and multiply by 100
```

In words, it counts the number of missing values in each column of `X`, then divides the result by the number of rows in `airports` and multiplies by 100. Calculating the percentage of missing values in each column, assuming `X` has the same number of rows as `airports`.

It's strange to mix and match the columns of `X` with the `nrow(airports)`, I would expect those to be the same (that is, either `sapply(airports, ...) / nrow(airports)` or `sapply(X, ...) / nrow(X)`.

As I mentioned in comments, nothing is being "dropped". If you wanted to do a `sum` ignoring the `NA` values, you do `sum(foo, na.rm = TRUE)`. Instead, here, *what is being summed is `is.na(x)`, that is we are summing whether or not each value is missing: counting missing values. `sum(is.na(foo))` is the idiomatic way to count the number of `NA` values in `foo`.

In this case, where the goal is a percent not a count, we can simplify by using `mean()` instead of `sum() / n`:

```
# slightly simpler, consistent object
sapply(airports, function(x) mean(is.na(x))) * 100
```

We could also use `is.na()` on the entire data so we don't need the "anonymous function":

```
# rearrange for more simplicity
sapply(is.na(airports), mean) * 100
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I appreciate it!